# Why does flutter packages get fail? Same directory cloned from github but on one pc package get fail

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter, dart-pub, flutter-dependencies

Cloned from github a flutter repo onto Laptop(win10) and Desktop (win7) but on Desktop **package get fail with error code 1**

First two images show success on laptop pc.

[image]
[image]

See Below Desktop Fails to get packages.
Where should I correct this on Desktop?

[image]
[image]

However, I can create new app without any error on Desktop.
Please help, Thank you.

Comment: It's a bit weird but from what I remember reinstalling Flutter seems to have solved this for others.

Comment: How to uninstall? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Deleting the Flutter install directory should do.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the two log files and also pubspec.lock file and run Flutter Get Packages. This Resolved the issue. This agonizing error ate up few hours.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

1. flutter clean
2. flutter packages get

it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).